# Replace a range of tokens within a string

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk

I have the following string:

```
this and this and this and this and this and this
```

and I want to uppercase the 3rd to the 5th occurrence of the token `this`:

```
this and this and THIS and THIS and THIS and this
```

The string does not contain newlines.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Why isn't this a simple `printf` problem?

Comment: @sarnold if you know a way using printf please share it.

Comment: `printf "this and this and THIS and THIS and THIS and this\n";`.

Comment: Would this 3rd to 5th occurrence also stretch across lines? I.e. is the counter reset every linebreak?

Comment: @TPL `The string does not contain newlines.` but there could be multiple lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**just echo `patten` 3 times:**(same as `SiegeX`'s solution)

```
$ echo "this and this and this and this and this and this" | sed "/this/{`echo 's//\U&/3;'{,,}`}"
this and this and THIS and THIS and THIS and this
```

Comment: To ameliorate this solution `sed "/this/{$(printf 's//\U&/3;%.s' {3..5})}"`

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $delimiter = " and ";
my $inputLine = <>;
chomp $inputLine;
my @thises = split($delimiter, $inputLine);
my $thisIdx = 0;
my @results;
foreach my $this (@thises) {
  if (($thisIdx >= 2) && ($thisIdx <= 4)) {
    push @results, uc($this);
  }
  else {
    push @results, $this;
  }
  $thisIdx++;
}
print STDOUT join($delimiter, @results)."\n";
```

Then:

```
$ echo "this and this and this and this and this and this" | ./test.pl
this and this and THIS and THIS and THIS and this
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty short one-liner with `sed`

```
sed '/this/{s//\U&/3;s//\U&/3;s//\U&/3;}'
```

#### Output

```
$ echo "this and this and this and this and this and this" | sed '/this/{s//\U&/3;s//\U&/3;s//\U&/3;}'
this and this and THIS and THIS and THIS and this
```

Answer (score 3):

### Perl

Use the `/e` modifier:

```
my $count;
$str =~ s{this}{ 3 <= ++$count && $count <= 5 ? THIS : this }eg;
```

As a one-liner:

```
perl -pi.bak -E 's/this/ 3 <= ++$c && $c <= 5 ? THIS : this/eg' file
```

Comment: Could you change this into a one-liner?

Comment: `perl -pwe 'my $c; s/this/ (++$c >= 3) && ($c <= 5) ? uc($&) : $& /eg;'` perhaps. This all depends if the counter is reset each line.

Comment: +1. Nice one! I forgot about the existence of the 'e' modifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)if($x~/this/){i++;if(i>=3&&i<=5) $x=toupper($x)}}1' yourFile
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  echo "this and this and this and this and this and this"|awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)if($x~/this/){i++;if(i>=3&&i<=5) $x=toupper($x)}}1'
this and this and THIS and THIS and THIS and this
```

Comment: Isn't it better to do `$x=="this"` then `$x~/this/` in this particular case? It would prevent matching something like `mathis` or `thisa`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this....

```
my @str = split(/\s+/,$string);

$str[4] = uc($str[4]); # Uppercase fifth element...
.
.                      # Repeat here for each element you want...
.

$string = join(' ',@str);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for me:

```
echo "this and this and this and this and this and this" | 
sed 's/this/&\n/6g;s/this[^\n]/\U&/3g;s/\n//g'
this and this and THIS and THIS and THIS and this
```

Explanation:

The 3rd to the 5th occurrence of the object string might be referred to as the `m'th` to the `n'th`

1. Append a newline (or any character not present in the line) to the object string from the `m'th+1` globally.
2. Alter or replace the object string from the `n'th` occurrence globally.
3. Remove all newlines thus restoring the original object strings

For this example, this appears to work too:

```
sed 's/this/\U&/3ig;s//\L&/6g'
```

As does this:

```
sed ':a;s/this/\U&/3;s/^/\n/;/^\n\{3\}/!ba;s///'
```